# How do you insert a multi dimensional array into a database`?

Tags: laravel

I have this array called `vakkes` I want to insert into the database

```
array:15 [▼
  "_token" => "VPC5jBKnYapzKv39aUsEFmDHJFwqKh1bqQ0lPp3M"
  "role" => "teacher"
  "last_name" => "Maya"
  "name" => "Vusumzi Maya"
  "email" => "maya.vusumzi@gmail.com"
  "phone" => "0719087970"
  "gender" => "Female"
  "identity" => "1233454567677"
  "street" => "30 Sabalele street,"
  "suburb" => "Port Elizabeth"
  "city" => "Port Elizabeth"
  "province" => "Eastern Cape"
  "code" => "6211"
  "klasses" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "3"
  ]
  "vakkes" => array:3 [▼
    1 => array:1 [▼
      0 => "Mathematics"
    ]
    2 => array:1 [▼
      0 => "Physical Science"
    ]
    3 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "Mathematics"
      1 => "Physical Science"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Here is my Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        ...

        $user = new User();
        $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->phone = $request->phone;
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);
        $user->gender = $request->gender;
        $user->identity = $request->identity;
        $user->street = $request->street;
        $user->suburb = $request->suburb;
        $user->city = $request->city;
        $user->province = $request->province;
        $user->code = $request->code;
        $user->school = $request->school;
        $user->save();
        
        $user->attachRole($request->role);
  

        $user->klasses()->sync($request->klasses); 

            if($request->vakkes){

               // What to write here?
                
            }

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', $user->name . ' has been created successfully');
    }
```

I have a One to Many relationship with `Klass` and `Vakke` Models

Comment: Do you allow duplicate values in `Vakke` table because as your request says you will have duplicate with `Mathematics` and `Physical Science` for the same user ?

Comment: Yes they are allowed... a User can have klasses and within those classes vakkes

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
$user->klasses()->each(function (Klass $klass) use ($request) {
   $klass->vakke()->sync($request['vakkes'][$klass->id]); 
})
```

Here i'm getting `$user->klasses` and fetching each `klass` vakke from the `$request['vakke']` and syncing the relation.

**Better Approach**

You can use database [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers), so you will have an `UserObserver` and when a new user created you sync your `Klass` and `Vakke` relation.